# create transparent overlay as background for bottom sheet

Tags: javascript, react-native, overlay, bottom-sheet

I had created bottom sheet using this [plugin][1]
Below is the code
[1]: https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

Issue is transparent overlay create opacity for bottomsheet also.
Is there any way i can create full screen transparent overlay and then proper bottomsheet without any opacity or tranparency.

```
const BottomSheet: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    overlay: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      opacity: 0.6,
      elevation: 24, 
      zIndex: 24,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    contentContainer: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      height: '100%',
      overflow: 'visible',
    },
    imageContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    bodyContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      height: 88,
      width: '100%',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    backgroundContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'green',
   },
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.overlay}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        snapPoints={['50%', '50%']}
        backgroundStyle={styles.backgroundContainer}
        containerStyle={{
          borderTopLeftRadius: 24,
          borderTopRightRadius: 24,
        }}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image source={props.imageSource} style={styles.largeImage} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>{props.body}</View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Divider style={styles.divider} />
          <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.bodyContainer}
              onPress={() => {
                props.onCancelAction();
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>
                {props.cancelText ? props.cancelText : 'Cancel'}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Divider style={styles.verticalDivider} />
          </View>
        </View>
    </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you try `backdropComponent` and `backgroundStyle` props?  backgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#1C1C1E' }}
                backdropComponent={(props) => (
                    <BottomSheetBackdrop disappearsOnIndex={-1} appearsOnIndex={0} opacity={0} {...props} />
                )}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
//add this
import BottomSheet, {
  BottomSheetBackdrop
} from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet"

//add this
const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props) => (
      <BottomSheetBackdrop
        opacity={0}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
        onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
        {...props}
      />
    ),
    [],
  )

<BottomSheet
    ref={bottomSheetRef}
    index={snapPointIndex}
    snapPoints={animatedSnapPoints}
    handleHeight={animatedHandleHeight}
    contentHeight={animatedContentHeight}
    keyboardBlurBehavior="restore"
    enableDynamicSizing={true}
    backdropComponent={renderBackdrop} //add this
>
</BottomSheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the opacity to the backgroundColor. For ex.: backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!